# Operation not permitted when trying to use openFile in OS X

Tags: macos, haskell

While trying to read file on Mac using the below Haskell code, I am getting an error that permission is denied: Operation not permitted.

```
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do
  inh <- openFile "/Users/lambda/Downloads/file.doc" ReadMode
  inpStr <- hGetContents inh
  let [(result,_)] = parse allDigits inpStr
  putStr result
  hClose inh

result : ** Exception: /Users/lambda/Downloads/file.doc: openFile: permission denied (Operation not permitted)
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the permissions? Can you open that file in other programs?

Comment: I am logged in using the admin user and it have read write access to the file

Comment: `hClose inh` is invalid. `hGetContents` already closes the file.

Comment: Possibly related? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101328/file-cant-be-moved-by-root-on-os-x

Comment: unfortunetly it does not work